# How can CPU usage max out at 50% but not use one CPU effectively?

Tags: java, cpu, cpu-usage, single-threaded

Suppose I have a java program that is thread-bound to one-CPU. From the left hand of the graph below - we can see one of the two CPUs is maxed out. (It has held this position for a while).

But the graph on the right shows that the different CPUs are doing different activities and one is not blocked.

[image]

My question is: **How can CPU usage max out at 50% but not use one CPU effectively?**

Comment: Question "how to use CPU nof effectively" has no direct answer (has millions answer).

Comment: this is likely hyper threading your seeing... where MS applies 2 threads of execution per core

Comment: What CPU is this?

Comment: Right click on the process and check the affinity. Unless you prevent this a process jumps from one core to the other

Comment: Could you expand that into an answer @Marged ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your process only uses only one core / CPU Windows tries to distribute the load over all available cores. This happens so fast / often that it looks like no core is ever used to 100%.

If you tell Windows to only use one core, you will see this one reach 100%. You can do this either by opening `taskmgr` and right clicking on the process and choosing `affinity` or when starting the application.

I can show you how this is done with `7z` because it does not matter which (single core) application you use, the effect is the same.

`start /affinity 0x1 7z b -mmt1` does start 7z and using `/affinity 0x1` assigns the first core as the only core. (`b -mmt1` is there to put 7-zip into benchmark mode which uses only one thread)
If you launched the process regularly you can see / change the affinity from taskmgr.
[image: affinity of a process]

The CPU chart will in both cases show 100%:

[image: 100% on a single core]

All screenshots above are from a German Windows 10, this is how it would look like on an English Windows 7:
[image]